# Difference between avaya DialogDesigner and OrchestraDesigner

Tags: ivr, vxml, avaya

I started to work directly in avaya OD but i dont have any knowledge regarding the advancement of avaya OD from DD.Can anyone please give information about the difference between avaya DD and avaya OD and related documents.

Comment: OD is almost the same as DD. But, probably OD supported "OR" and "AND" operator, and it has local mode "Reusable Module".

Answer (score 1):

Orchestration Designer is basically new marketing name for the next release of Dialog Designer. I have developed voice applications for voice/experience portal and didn't find any fundamental differences between the two.